# How to convert id to text for category PHP

Tags: php

how to convert id to text for category for example

```
cat_id='1' to NEWS
cat_id='2' to Hardware
cat_id='3' to Software
```

That's my code to article:
/*
Kategoria > `<?php echo ( $lajmifundit1['cat_id']); ?>`

and thus appear in browser:
to News:
Kategoria > 1

or other article
to: Hardware

Kategoria > 2
how to replace id 1 to NEWS and id 2 to Hardware

Please Help me..!

Comment: Are you using a framework? Are you wanting this in URLs? Some clarification in where you're using these IDs, and want the category instead is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the name of the category saved somewhere, for now you only have the category id.
This having said here's an example:

```
$category = array(
   1 => "News",
   2 => "Hardware",
   3 => "Software",
);

foreach ($category as $name ) {
   echo $name;
}
```